# How to create Ubuntu graphic C programs without Gtk?

Tags: graphics, application-development, gtk, c

Is there some sort of program or something to turn your text program graphical in **C**?

Thank You,

CCM

Comment: Depends on what you need. If you need just a simple popup, you can  call `zenity` - it's a command-line application. So all you need is basically `popen()`  that command and read it's output.

Comment: There are plenty of other toolkits that can be used. Why specifically do you not want gtk+, but do want C?

Comment: Because gtk is basically a language in and of itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way with calling external program - `zenity`. This way your command-line C code is now a GUI app by virtue of using zenity's simple input popup dialog, although this method isn't particularly secure.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *zenity;
    char answer[getpagesize()];

    if ((zenity = popen("zenity --entry","r")) != NULL){

        fgets(answer,sizeof(answer),zenity);
        printf("User's answer:%s\n",answer);
        exit(0);
    }
    // we get here if above check failed
    perror("zenity exited with non-zero exit code");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you do more advanced graphics options in zenity, like gtk color and sound and window color text, position?

Comment: @ChristooherM Not really. `zenity` has set of popups prebuilt. You can customize some, like `--form`. But also look into `yad` , that tool is more flexible. But  zenity comes preinstalled. If you need Gtk graphics and  more or less easy code, consider switching to Python, maybe with Tk ( a built in GUI module )